# Vue.js onchange using Base Select component

Tags: vue.js, select, vuejs2, vue-component, onchange

I am working through  and attempting to alter an example piece of code, so that @change events are triggered from a base select input child component.

The *base* component is the following

```js
<template>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>{{ label }}</label>
    <select
      class="form-control"
      :class="{
        'is-valid': validator && !validator.$error && validator.$dirty,
        'is-invalid': validator && validator.$error
      }"
      @change="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
    >
      <option
        v-for="opt in options"
        :key="opt.value"
        :value="opt.value"
        :selected="value === opt.value"
      >
        {{ opt.label || 'No label' }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    label: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    options: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
      validator (opts) {
        return !opts.find(opt => typeof opt !== 'object')
      }
    },
    value: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    validator: {
      type: Object,
      required: false,
      validator ($v) {
        return $v.hasOwnProperty('$model')
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and the *child* component has the reference

```js
<BaseSelect 
    label="What do you love most about Vue?" 
    :options="loveOptions"
    v-model="$v.form.love"
    v-on:change="changeItem($event)"      
/>

...

methods: {
    changeItem (event) {
      console.log('onChange')
      console.log(event.target.value)
    },
```

It appears the method is not being hit, it works as expected when I use a *select* input rather than the *BaseSelect*, so I suspect there is something missing or not quite right in the setup here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are emitting an `input` event, but listening for a `change` event:

```
@change="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"

...

v-on:change="changeItem($event)"
```

Comment: Legend! Thanks TommyF